# React accessing file data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, file

In a React/Typescript app I have a component that accepts a file:

```
<div>
     <input type="file" {...register('avatar')} />
</div>
```

along with 2 string values. These values are all saved to `FormData`:

```
type FormData = {
  handle: string;
  role: string;
  avatar: File;
};

const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<FormData>();
```

I would like to access the avatar file name to use later on, as well as send the file to an AWS bucket like this:

```
const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.avatar.name);
    ReactS3Client.uploadFile(data.avatar, data.handle + Date.now())
      .then((data) => console.log(data))
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

There are a few problems happening here. First of all, when I console.log avatar.name it is simply blank. In one of my tests the file was Player.jpg, so I expected it to log "Player". Next, when I check my AWS bucket the file was indeed uploaded but when I try to open it I do not see an image and instead see: `[object FileList`.

Obviously somewhere in the process I am interacting with the uploaded file incorrectly. How can I access the name of the file and correctly upload it to AWS?

EDIT:

If I `console.log(data.avatar);` it gives me this:

[image: avatar]

If I `console.log(data.avatar.name);` which is an autofill option in VS Code then it simply prints undefined.

If I `console.log(data.avatar[0].name);` I get this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'File'. Property '0' does not exist on type 'File'.ts(7053)`.

How can I access that name property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that `console.log(data.avatar[0].name);` will give you what you need.

Comment: Well this was the first thing I thought as well, but this gives me this error: ````Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'File'.
  Property '0' does not exist on type 'File'.ts(7053)```` how can I fix that?

Comment: I figured it out though. I made avatar a FileList instead of File and it worked. Thanks man, I will give you the credit!

Comment: You are welcome, if you couldn't change the type for whatever reason, casting the type may have worked too, i.e  `console.log((data.avatar[0] as FileList).name);`